# Mandrill Add Event Webhook Unable To Set Delay

Tags: json, rest, mandrill

This might end up being a silly question I am trying to add an event webhook through the API and cannot switch the delayed event on.

```
{ 
   "key": "[my_key_is_a_unique_snowflake]",
    "url": "[http://randomwebsite.com/api/accept]",
    "description": "Defer Events",
    "events": [
           "defer", "deferred", "delay", "delayed"
    ]
}
```

Obviously I tried each of these separately, but results similar to:

```
"message":"Validation error: {\"events\":[null,null,null,\"Value must be one of: send, hard_bounce, soft_bounce, open, click, spam, unsub, reject, blacklist, whitelist (not defer)\"]
```

I have tried "defer" and "delay" amongst other permutations of these words, etc. I cannot figure this out. I can see the lonely checkbox, sitting there alone and unchecked. He wants to be checked, why can't he be loved like all the other event checkboxes?

Help me automate this thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is an issue with our validator (ie, we didn't add the new event when we made those deferrals available via webhook).  The event name is 'deferral', but we'll need to update the validator and the docs before that will work.

Comment: Awesome! I really appreciate. Is there somewhere I can go to be notified of when it is fixed?

Comment: It looks like you may have submitted a ticket to our support team as well. They should follow up once it's resolved, and I can post back here once we've pushed that. I don't have an ETA at the moment, unfortunately.